# How do I make text in a UILabel wrap around a certain character?

Tags: ios, uilabel, word-wrap

I have a UILabel being populated from data from a database.  The data comes in like this:

> LV:7:00 AM - 10:00 PM,S:7:00 AM - 10:00 PM,D:9:00 AM - 10:00 PM

I want it to wrap around the comma so the UILabel looks like this:

```
LV:7:00 AM - 10:00 PM, 
S:7:00 AM - 10:00 PM,
D:9:00 AM - 10:00 PM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I hadnt set the UILabel to more than 1 line.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
myLabel.text = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@",\n"];
```

Comment: its doesnt seem to work.  Its doesnt do anything, i still get the text truncated as it reaches the end of the UILabel.